# VLC gets java headless error on Blu-ray discs

Tags: java, vlc-media-player, blu-ray

I have been using VLC for a long time, watching Blu-rays but unable to access the menus due to a "Java not found" type of error.  My environment is Fedora 32, x64

I installed the library that vlc was looking for : `libbluray-bdj` and I have been unable to get any Blu-ray disk to play.  VLC outputs this:

```
$ vlc /dev/sr1
VLC media player 3.0.11.1 Vetinari (revision 3.0.11.1-0-g52483f3ca2)
[000055bcae1c25b0] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
dec.c:245: WARNING: using libmmbd for BD+. On-disc menus won't work with all discs.
org.videolan.BDJActionQueue:0: ERROR: Callback timeout in Thread[BDJLoader.BDJActionQueue,5,main], callback=org.videolan.BDJLoader$BDJLoaderAction@382cb045

java.lang.Long.toHexString(Long.java:272)
org.videolan.CacheDir.getCacheRoot(CacheDir.java:87)
org.videolan.CacheDir.create(CacheDir.java:110)
org.videolan.VFSCache.init(VFSCache.java:56)
org.videolan.VFSCache.createInstance(VFSCache.java:39)
org.videolan.BDJLoader.loadN(BDJLoader.java:173)
org.videolan.BDJLoader.access$200(BDJLoader.java:46)
org.videolan.BDJLoader$BDJLoaderAction.doAction(BDJLoader.java:363)
org.videolan.BDJAction.process(BDJAction.java:59)
org.videolan.BDJActionQueue.run(BDJActionQueue.java:86)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
VFSCache.java:org.videolan.VFSCache.init:61: disc root is in UDF
org.videolan.BDJLoader:0: ERROR: loadN() failed: java.awt.HeadlessException
java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
java.awt.BDRootWindow.<init>(BDRootWindow.java:32)
org.videolan.GUIManager.<init>(GUIManager.java:28)
org.videolan.GUIManager.createInstance(GUIManager.java:36)
org.videolan.BDJLoader.loadN(BDJLoader.java:228)
org.videolan.BDJLoader.access$200(BDJLoader.java:46)
org.videolan.BDJLoader$BDJLoaderAction.doAction(BDJLoader.java:363)
org.videolan.BDJAction.process(BDJAction.java:59)
org.videolan.BDJActionQueue.run(BDJActionQueue.java:86)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
GUIManager:0: ERROR: getInstance(): no instance !
GUIManager:0: ERROR: getInstance(): no instance !
dec.c:245: WARNING: using libmmbd for BD+. On-disc menus won't work with all discs.
[00007f0530001ea0] libbluray demux: First play: 1, Top menu: 1
HDMV Titles: 5, BD-J Titles: 86, Other: 0
VFSCache.java:org.videolan.VFSCache.init:61: disc root is in UDF
org.videolan.BDJLoader:0: ERROR: loadN() failed: java.awt.HeadlessException
java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
java.awt.BDRootWindow.<init>(BDRootWindow.java:32)
org.videolan.GUIManager.<init>(GUIManager.java:28)
org.videolan.GUIManager.createInstance(GUIManager.java:36)
org.videolan.BDJLoader.loadN(BDJLoader.java:228)
org.videolan.BDJLoader.access$200(BDJLoader.java:46)
org.videolan.BDJLoader$BDJLoaderAction.doAction(BDJLoader.java:363)
org.videolan.BDJAction.process(BDJAction.java:59)
org.videolan.BDJActionQueue.run(BDJActionQueue.java:86)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
GUIManager:0: ERROR: getInstance(): no instance !
```

I have tried multiple Blu-ray discs as well as tried cvlc.  I get the same error every time.

This seems more like a java error than a VLC one, but I cannot figure this out.  Internet research has turned up nothing. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following packages installed (names may differ per distribution, these are from Fedora 33):

- libbluray
- libbluray-bdj
- libbdplus

Fedora 33 has Java 11 installed so install the following package:

- java-11-openjdk

Installing the above package fixes the java.awt.HeadlessException error.

If you have another of version of Java installed, make sure you install the corresponding package. E.g. for Java 8 on Fedora it's 'java-1.8.0-openjdk'.

Then make sure you have $JAVA_HOME set in your environment when you start vlc. You can test this manually with:

```
$ JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre vlc
```

Now when you open your Bluray iso in VLC it should start showing the menus.